# Python threading with OpenCV works fine on Windows but freezes on Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, opencv, ubuntu

I have try to make an script in Ubuntu with two cameras, opening two captures with cv2.VideoCapture() and calling them from two different threads, but the script just freezes without raising any error.

I have tried the exact same script on Windows with the same computer (I have two partitions on the computer, one with Windows 10 and the other with Ubuntu 20.04) and it works totally fine.

The code is this one:

```
import threading
import cv2

def base_Videocapture(nr_camera):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(nr_camera)

    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("Video" + str(nr_camera), img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()

def camera0():
    base_Videocapture(0)

def camera1():
    base_Videocapture(2)

t0 = threading.Thread(target=camera0)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=camera1)

t0.start()
t1.start()
```

Thanks in advance.

Note: I know that I can make a main thread and call both VideoCaptures in the same function, but in my project `def base_Videocapture` contains more code than just show the images of the multiple cameras. And also I want to know why the same code works fine on Windows and not in Linux.

Comment: you have to keep all gui calls (imshow, waitKey, etc) on the main thread